# Sources for Mars rover sensor data

Tags: mars, curiosity, opportunity, spirit, pathfinder

Is it possible to get sensor data from past or present martian rovers sent by NASA?

Specifically, I'm looking for accelerometer and wheel torque data from the rovers. I've searched their "official" sites but the most information I can find there is just image data and the sites seem to be aimed at the general public, not researchers. Is there another path that I could take to get this type of information?

Comment: data.nasa.gov is the place for stuff like this. [Here's the tag with all of Curiosity's (=Mars Science Laboratory) data](https://data.nasa.gov/browse?tags=mars%20science%20laboratory). Data about the rover's position, velocity, orientation,... is found in the [SPICE kernels](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_mars.html)